Message delievering through local host of react app but not after deploying on netlify

I have a react app which is basically my portfolio app with backend made with django. But, the message is delievering through local host of react but after deploying it on netlify i am not able to deliever the message.

i tried to use CORS_ALLOW_ORIGINS with specific list of my local host as well as of my backend server but still not working.
The error on deployed app console is :-
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://wahab901278.pythonanywhere.com/contact/submit/” index-DUkXO2lH.js:628:7274
Error: Network Error index-DUkXO2lH.js:631:4990
How to fix that anyone please assist
